# yasnippet weird-input when org-mode :tag: on same line

Tags: emacs, org-mode, yasnippet

I am trying to create a yasnippet for new projects in org-mode.

The beginning of the yasnippet looks like this.

```
# -*- mode: snippet -*-
# name: project
# key: project
# --
#+TAGS: project(p)

* $1
* $2                                :project:
```

However, I have the following problem on the line with the :project: tag.
The input is input with large spaces between each letter. Is this a problem in org-mode or does the org-mode syntax for tags represent something in yasnippet definitions?

![image]